# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name shared accross all applications of same website: isn't this insecure?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm very surprised: I have created 2 independant applications (let's say for 2 different clients) under same website. I have separate login/password list in each web.config but I can get HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name of first application into second application !

Sessions variables are not shared between the 2 though, still this is quite insecure for HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name? It would mean client 2 would be able to access client 1 user browsing to client 2 application without authenticating into client 2 website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a different decryption key in the machinekey element in the web.config of each app, it will ensure that users cannot navigate between the apps without re-logging in.

Example below which came from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<machineKey
  validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
  decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
  validation="SHA1" />
```

You might also be able to use the IsolateApps modifier instead of generating keys, but I find that specifically setting the keys at the level you want them to be shared gives you more control over the process. You can find various tools online for generating these keys or you can roll your own based on Microsoft's crypto classes.

Note that a key set in a web.config at a higher level in the IIS structure automatically flows "downhill" to the child apps unless you specifically override it in their web.config. It's possible that's what's happened in your case.